# How to get then show value from database in form select2

Tags: php, sql, jquery-select2

I try to get the value from database for showing the result and can change
values in select form

this is my code but it didn't print any values from database

```
    <select multiple="true" name="sele[]" id="select" style="width:300px">
    <?php
         $sort = mysqli_query ($con,"SELECT order_no FROM choose where Ad_num =".$_GET['pno'] ); 

                 if( mysqli_num_rows( $sort )==0){
                    echo "<tr><td colspan='4'>No Rows Returned</td></tr>";
                 }else{

                    $re = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $sort );

            ?>
    <?php
        for ($a=0; $a < count($sort); $a++){ ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $re["order_no"]; ?>"></option>
       <?php }
    ?>
```

thanks for your helping

Comment: Try to echo your query and check that what output you get.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the closing bracket of the else condition(in the php)
If you look at the bottom, you only close the for, and not the else. I don't know if you close it afterwards, but this may be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should try following :-

```
<select multiple="true" name="sele[]" id="select" style="width:300px">
<?php
     $sort = mysqli_query ($con,"SELECT order_no FROM choose where Ad_num =".$_GET['pno'] ); 

             if( mysqli_num_rows( $sort )==0){
                echo "<option value="">No Rows Returned</option>";
             }else{

                $re = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $sort );
             }

        ?>
<?php
    for ($a=0; $a < count($sort); $a++){ ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $re["order_no"]; ?>"></option>
   <?php }
?>
```

**Note :-** Also include some text between `<option></option>` tag to show some data to the user.

Comment: this code doesn't work too, it didn't print anything out

Comment: @ppppp: It is not printing anything because you are trying to put a table row inside `select` tag. Check the updated code. It will work now.